# node.js(meteor.js), multi-core usage with multi-program(process)

Tags: linux, node.js, meteor

I know there are so many multi-core thread here,
but I want to clear this simple subject.

If I run a lot of node.js or meteor.js project on single linux machine,
the each process is using each core automatically?

i.g. if run 3 process in 4 core machine, each process would be running on each core?

I'm sure this job scheduling is run by OS properly, but I have no idea how to see this running status visually. 
Because if OS allocates two or three processes to single core, that would be so waste of resources.

(P.S. please note some way to check this CPU usage status (not performance))

Thanks you.

Comment: Depends on your OS. On linux, OSX and Windows 7 and above you can do what's called CPU pinning which is to assign processes to CPU (also known as "affinity"). Depending on the OS this pinning may be strict or relaxed (either the process cannot run on any other CPU or it just have a preference). Google "cpu pinning" or "cpu affinity". This has nothing to do with node.js though. It's part of the features provided by your OS. Also depending on OS google pros and cons of CPU pinning. On Linux the general advice is to let the OS figure it out and don't pin unless you really need to